# How can I add banded lines to the end of cinnamon sticks(or sheets of wood)?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects, shaders

I would like to make a realistic cinnamon stick and its shader. My approach is as much procedural as possible, but easier options are ok too.

Here is my first render:

[image]

And a reference image:

[image]

(3)I have noticed that there's a darker line can be seen at the both ends; how can I achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's more practical to finish the modelling first, or at least get as far as possible, else you might end up having to generate UV maps over and over again. Make the Objects look great rendered without textures, then add  textures.

Comment: Second that. Modelling seems like the first step here. Once you've got that right, texturing should not be that easy.

Comment: Asking several questions does not work well with this site's format.  It makes searching difficult and answers end up being specific to a particular project instead of being useful for many different projects.  It also means that someone who can answer one part but not another will have difficulty dealing with the while thing.  It's better if you break down each component and ask them as a separate questions.  Feel free to post links for the new questions here so I'll get the notifications as they are ready.  I have a few ideas on some of the other parts.  :)

Comment: @MarcClintDion thanks for the advice, yes makes sense to ask a direct specific question on one thing only. My priority here would be the overall texture of the stick, so I'll i make it under a new question, no worries

Answer (score 1):

To add the darker banded lines on the ends of the model, you can make a linear gradient texture, instead, I used Google image search.

By selecting all of the edges and by pressing <kbd>u</kbd> ***UV Mapping->Follow Active Quads*** you should end up with a mapping that is proportional and square.  Be sure to select a face near an edge where you want the mapping to begin.  This will be the ***Active Quad*** which the algorithm uses as its basis.  You can see the active quad in the following image, it is pale compared to the other selections and also has a grid of white dots across it. Now rotate and scale the UV Coordinates to align properly with the image you selected.

[image]

The color doesn't matter because you can use an RBG To BW node to make it greyscale.

Here is what it looks like when rendered.

[image]

---

You can also use ***Generated Coordinates*** with a ***Wave Texture*** set to ***Bands***.  It works well for the model I made but this is because the model is planer and is rolled up with an Armature.  When the Armature Modifier is Applied, it no longer works.

[image]

[Here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/271/) is the Blend file. Select either of the Material Output nodes to make that material active.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer @marcClintDion , it's been very useful. and thanks for the file ,too. now if only i could get the rest of my cinnamon texture better :) I will make another question for it then

Comment: Morning @MarcClintDion, here is the new [question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32520/how-can-i-make-a-cinnamon-stick-material-procedural) for the material first, and i will be putting up another question for those flaky edges in abit ;)

Comment: and here is the flaky [question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32522/how-can-i-make-flaky-edges-for-cinnamon-stick)  @MarcClintDion

Comment: thanks again @MarcClintDion, yea i'll delete some of my comments too :)
saw your answer for the flaky part but didn't get a chance to study it properly so far, will do it asap. meanwhile do you have any idea about the other part of this cinnamon thing which is the overall material/texture?

Comment: as a matter of fact I do. ;) Just post the question.  If the name is a little off we can always edit it later.  Just post the link either here or on the other page so I see it.(ps, I'll delete this comment once the other question is up)

Comment: Link to part 2, making the flaked edges.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32522/how-can-i-make-flaky-edges-for-cinnamon-stick

Comment: Hi @MarcClintDion , this is the [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32520/how-can-i-make-this-cinnamon-stick-material-more-rough-and-dusty-looking)  to the texture part of the question, but i changed it to meet the requirements - it says my question is on hold :( thanks for your support btw